# How to catch the afterRender-event of modal window in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, modal-dialog, vuetify.js

I have a modal window created with Vuetify lib:

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialogFilters" max-width="1000px">
<template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-btn color="primary" dark class="mb-2 mr-2" v-on="on">Filters</v-btn>
</template>
<v-card>
    <v-card-title>
        <span class="headline">[[ formTitleFilters ]]</span>
    </v-card-title>

    <v-card-text>
        <div id="builder" class="container"></div>
        <v-container>
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-set">Set Rules</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-get">Get Rules</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" id="btn-reset">Reset</button>
            <div style="height: 10px"></div>
        </v-container>
    </v-card-text>

    <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="closeFilters">Cancel</v-btn>
        <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="saveFilters">Save</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```

This modal window contains `<div id="builder" class="container"></div>` which is supposed to be used by another JQuery lib (QueryBuilder) to render some elements. But Vue somehow hides the content of this modal window before it's opened, that's why my `div id="builder"` stays unfound. And I'd like to retrieve this div upon modal window is opened. But I couldn't make it work. I can't figure out how to catch that event when the modal window is rendered and I can use div on it. Would appreciate any help. (https://jsfiddle.net/trnvp8qc/)

Comment: Can you tell us which jQuery library is it? Maybe you can render it dynamically

Comment: I'm using JQuery Query Builder (https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution in the documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html.

This function "Vue.nextTick(callback)" helped.